# How to create my first Grails project in IntelliJ, with Maven?

Tags: maven-2, grails, intellij-idea

- **The goal**: create my first Grails project, in IntelliJ, with Maven support.
- **Myself**: Noob to Groovy/Grails, has some Maven experience but not too much
- **The tooling**: Groovy 1.7.5, IntelliJ 9.0.3 and Maven 2.0

What I've tried so far, is:

1. File->New Project
2. Create Module
3. Maven Module
4. Add & choose the Grails Archtype
5. Right click on the project --> Run --> grails

I'm getting errors:

- `PHP home is not specified` - WTF, does Grails require PHP?
- When I previously tried to use IntelliJ to create a Grails project **without** Maven, I actually managed to run the application - so I don't understand what is missing now.

P.S. I [reported this as an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-60265), vote it up if you want.

If anyone is interested, here is [a github project with all the bootstrap done](http://github.com/ripper234/Test-grails-project/tree/37f3478cc8fc56c0e9d932a3f096c7286ecb37de).

Comment: "WTF, does Grails require PHP?" - It does not :)

Comment: @Rob - Yeah, so what am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wish I could help, but I don't have much experience with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's leave IntelliJ aside for now and try to get started on the command line.

The following steps work for me (basically repeating the [official instructions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.5%20Ant%20and%20Maven) but using version 1.3.4):

First create an application:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.grails \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=grails-maven-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.4 \
    -DgroupId=example -DartifactId=my-app
```

And update `my-app/pom.xml` to use Java 6:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then `cd` into `my-app` and create the project structure (run maven from inside the project folder):

```
cd my-app
mvn initialize
```

Edit the `application.properties` file to add:

```
plugins.hibernate=1.3.4
plugins.tomcat=1.3.4
```

And run the following to install the plugins:

```
mvn compile
```

When done, you should be able to start your app

```
mvn grails:run-app
```

And to access it at http://localhost:8080/my-app/.

Once you get the above working, importing the project inside IntelliJ should be a trivial step. And if you still get a problem, it will be probably an IntelliJ related issue.

Comment: I'm following these steps, and get stuck in the 'application.properties' - there is no such file anywhere.

Comment: Well, the problem was that I ran 'mvn initialize' on the parent dir, instead of on the project dir. Works like a charm now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

user495750. It's an IntelliJ 9 thing. Nothing I've done (or I suspect ripper234 did). I upgraded an existing Grails project that was working fine from Grails 1.2.0 to 1.3.5 and IntelliJ screws things up. You do nothing to specify a PHP server. Suddenly it thinks there's no server configured.
I managed to get things working by pointing Intellij to the new Grails Home and that fixed things. No need for the Maven incantations. That's a long winded approach. BTW: It's best to get the 1.3.6 version out of Hudson and use that - I had some YUI plugin issues. So I had to do a second update.
Right click project -> Update Grails.. -> New SDK -> point to new Grails Home.
If I recall this invokes a grails upgrade automatically for you to upgrade. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Grails does not require PHP. You got that error because you created PHP run configuration instead Grails run configuration. PHP run configuration may be created on **any** project by right click on the project --> Run --> ProjectName. It is a PHP support issue.
Grails run configuration will be created automatically after initialization of project structure.